# Difference between Electron-based XMLHttpRequest and browser-based URL with query string?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, electron, query-string, easy-digital-downloads

I'm working on an `Electron` app and trying to integrate the `Easy Digital Downloads` [Software Licensing](https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/384-software-licensing-api) WordPress plugin. I haven't done much with `HTTP` communication in Electron/Javascript so this may be a naive question.

**The problem:** I am able to get a license activation response from my EDD server and while there is no specific error, for some reason a license is not activated. The odd thing is that if I use a URL and query string in a browser with the same data, the plugin responds as expected: I can activate, deactivate and check the status of a license.

So EDD seems to be working and there are no errors with Electron. But something is missing. Initially I was using the [net](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/net) Electron module but after this issue came up, I switched to using the [example script from EDD](https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/1038-software-licensing-api---example-using-javascript) (below) which uses `XMLHttpRequest`. With that I get the following response back:

> {"success":true,"license":"valid","item_id":539,"item_name":"My
>   Awesome App","license_limit":1,"site_count":0,"expires":"2020-12-19
>   23:59:59","activations_left":1,"checksum":"f2d66c6844b37d1fa931b813c408",
>   "payment_id":248,"customer_name":"Marvin
>   Gardens","customer_email":"marvin@home.com","price_id":false}

Which is fine except that **"activations_left":1** never changes and it should given "license_limit":1. So something is wrong.

On the other hand, if I use a URL with a query string in a browser, the "activations_left" is decremented and license activation only works once (as it should). For example, this works:

`http://YOURSITE.com/?edd_action=activate_license&item_id=8&license=cc22c1ec86304b36883440e2e84cddff&url=http://licensedsite.com`

**My Question:** is there some fundamental difference between these two methods? Is there something I need to add to my `XMLHttpRequest`? I have a support ticket open with EDD but I need to keep moving with this. And sorry to be so long-winded!

---

**UPDATE:**
@aw04 suggested I try using `GET` – just tried that and I "get" the same response as before: no error but also no activation.

Could there be some property which should (or shouldn't) be in the `Electron` request which is (or isn't) in a browser request by default?

```
 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
      console.log('xhttp.responseText', xhttp.responseText);
    }
  }

  var url = "http://YOURSITE.com/?edd_action=activate_license&item_id=8&license=cc22c1ec86304b36883440e2e84cddff"
  xhttp.open("GET", url);
  xhttp.send();
```

---

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var postUrl = 'http://<domain.com>/edd-sl/';

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }   
}

var data = {
    edd_action: 'check_license', 
    license:    '<license key>',
    item_name:  encodeURIComponent('<item name>'),
};

xhttp.open("POST", postUrl, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://local.dev");

var values = '';
for (var key in data){
    values += key + '=' + data[ key ] + '&';
}
values = values.substring(0, values.length - 1);
xhttp.send(values);
```

Comment: you should probably edit out your personal information?

Comment: you are issuing a POST whereas the browser does a GET. you might try that and just build out the query string, see what happens

Comment: @aw04 - thanks. Just tried that (and updated the question with the code). I get the same result: no error but also no activation. Weird.

Comment: @kemicofasupportsMonica – thanks. I think I did edit out the personal info ("Marvin Gardens" is a name from the game Monopoly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some help from Easy Digital Downloads support folks, this is resolved.

The issue had to do with a property in their `Software Licensing` plugin setup: "Do not check URL". I hadn't enabled that with the result that my API call from `Electron` failed and the one using a browser succeeded because the browser was adding headers that Electron was not.

After enabling "Do not check URL", calls from within `Electron` work. I guess there is also an option to pass in a URL, but since I am using EDD for licensing desktop software, that didn't seem like a needed option.

Anyway, hope this helps someone.